# alertbox in android

Tags: android

```
AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

when i wrote this error is shawn that

```
The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new Runnable(){}) is undefined
```

.. so just tell me what i m do...

Comment: give the complete code where you have problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you trying to run a dialog from Runnable? you cannot pass runnable as the context. you should replace "this" by YourActivityClassName.this in order to pass your activity's context into constructor.

if this construction is within a thread, then i guess it's kinda wrong, cause you shound't perform any UI operations from different threads. you should use handlers to pass messages to the main activity.. i may be wrong though, cause i don't see the whole code

Answer (score 0):

If you place your mouse over the underligned error eclipse should offer you to import AlertDialog.
If it does not, you can add the import manualy

import android.app.AlertDialog